# Long running query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

[image: picture2][image: picture]I have a SQL query to load from a view into a table, it is running for more than 45 minutes now. I have checked if there is any blocking issue but this is the only query running and I am not using any index in a destination table. It only takes 5 minutes to create the underlying view. It has 5 million records.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1]
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        Service = STUFF ((SELECT ',' + Service
                          FROM Table2 T1
                          WHERE T1.Resource = T2.Resource
                          ORDER BY Service 
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 
        Tag = STUFF ((SELECT ',' + Tag
                      FROM Table2 T1
                      WHERE T1.Resource = T2.Resource
                      ORDER BY Tag 
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 
        Resource, 
        MAX(SubjectIdentifier) AS SubjectIdentifier, 
        DataType
    FROM 
        Table2 T2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
    GROUP BY 
        Name, Resource, DataType
```

How can I optimize this query and load it fast? Thanks

Comment: Show us the **table structure** and let us know if you have any **indexes** on that table (and if so - how are they defined?)

Comment: And show the expected execution plan.

Comment: Does Table1 have any triggers defined? On what kind of storage your database/log files reside?

Comment: There is no indexes in both tables and i have added the execution plan at the top.

Comment: @Arvo Both tables do not have triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you cannot use `string_agg()` because you are using an old version of SQL Server.

I would suggest rewriting your query a little bit and then adding indexes:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Service = STUFF((SELECT ',' + TT2.Service
                        FROM Table2 TT2
                        WHERE TT2.Resource = T2.Resource
                        ORDER BY TT2.Service 
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, ''
                      ), 
       Tag = STUFF((SELECT ',' + TT2.Tag
                    FROM Table2 TT2
                    WHERE TT2.Resource = T2.Resource
                    ORDER BY TT2.Tag 
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                   ), 1, 1, ''
                  ), 
       Resource, 
       MAX(SubjectIdentifier) AS SubjectIdentifier, 
       DataType
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name, Resource, DataType
       FROM Table2 T2
      ) T2;
```

Then, you want indexes on:

- `Table2(Name, Resource, DataType)`
- `Table2(Resource, Service)`
- `Table2(Resource, Tax)`

In addition, it is suspicious that you are aggregating by three columns but only using one of them in the subqueries.  I would expect all three in the subqueries.

Also notice that I qualified *all* column references.